# How to get a list of Shared Domain libraries

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly

I have a service that loads plugins on demand.  These plugins load various .Net libraries.  Some are loaded in to the Shared Domain for use by multiple plugins. Is there a way to programmatically obtain a list of the libraries that are in the Shared Domain?

Comment: Show us some code.

Comment: If your code can access the `AppDomain` object, it has the methods.

Comment: Thank you for your reply to my inquiry.  Do you happen to know what method(s) in the AppDomain object will let you determine whether or not the library has been loaded in to the Shard Domain (e.g. Domain Neutral)?